# Why is my React code's try catch block not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

MY REACT CODE IS:

```
import { type } from "@testing-library/user-event/dist/type";

import React, { useState } from "react";

import "./clint.css";

export default function Addtask() {
  const [task, setTask] = useState([]);

  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      setTask([...task, text]);

      const resp = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/addtask", {
        method: "POST",

        body: JSON.stringify(text),

        headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
      });

      if (resp.status === 201) {
        alert("task added successfully");
      } else {
        alert("some error occurred while uploading");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  function change(e) {
    const ip = e.target.value;

    setText(ip);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>add user component</h1>

      <span>Add Task</span>

      <input onChange={change} placeholder="add a task" />

      <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
        submit
      </button>

      <ul>
        {task.map((task) => (
          <li>{task}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

MY NODE JS CODE IS:

```
const express = require("express");

const storage = require("node-persist");

const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

storage.init();

app.use(cors());

app.post("/addtask", async (req, res) => {
  const { task } = req.body;

  try {
    const resp = await storage.setItem(task);

    res.send("task added");
  } catch (error) {
    res.send({ message: "some error occured", error });

    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.listen(5000);
```

MY POSTMAN CODE IS:

```
{

"task": "go shop"

}
```

postman url is http://localhost:5000/addtask which is running in post method.

But why does my React js code's try catch block not working?

Comment: What do you expect it to catch? You're never sending an error status code, and `fetch` doesn't raise on error statuses anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The fetch API does not throw on network requests that succeeded (i.e yielded data), so if you get a response that isn't a 200, 201, or 202, throw your own error [as per the Fetch API docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

So in this case, don't use `alert("some error occurred while uploading");` when your code encounters the wrong http status, create an *actual* error and throw that:

```
...
try {
  if (resp.status === 201) {
    popup.notice(`task added successfully`);
  } else {
    throw new Error(`task could not be added (status:${resp.status})`);
  }
} catch (e) {
  popup.error(e.message);
}
```

In the assumption you're using a proper popup library for transient page notifications (since those are side effects of your component doing what it needs to do). And if you don't use console.log

(Because of course as a general rule, don't *ever* use `alert`, just do your dev work with your console open, which you're almost certainly already doing, and use console.error, console.warn, console.log, etc. so you can see all your data, not string coercions)